# Infinite random walk problem

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

A frog is standing on an infinite number line at position 20.  At the end of every minute he jumps from position $x$ to one of {$x-1$, $x+1$, $x+2$}, each with probability $1\over 3$.

The frog will get eaten if he reaches position 0.  (Let's say a cat is waiting there.)

What's the probability that the frog will get eaten?  (Is there a general solution to this for starting position $n$?)

Since the frog jumps both ways and the playing field is infinite, I haven't been able to find a way to solve it using recurrence relations or solving a system of equations.  Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: Didn't you just asked almost the exact same question and received a link to a note on recurrence relations? Let $p(n)$ be probability that a frog survives starting at $n$. Then $p(\le 0)=0$ and $p(i)=\sum_j P(j-i)p(j)$ holds. Solve it subject to constraints that $\lim_{i\to\infty} p(i)=[\mu>0]$ and $p$ is non-decreasing.

Comment: Solving the recurrence yields $p_n=1-(\sqrt 2-1)^n$

Comment: @A.S. Thanks, yeah, I didn't understand the link so I thought I'd ask a slightly different question that might help me understand better.  I'll read through it again.  But I don't understand your explanation either.  What's the recurrence relation you used?

Comment: Look at the end of the second line of my first comment.

Comment: @A.S. OK, I see the recurrence relation, but I don't understand how the constraints fit in and what you do with the recurrence relation.

Comment: @A.S. OK I had another read through the document and I believe I understand most of it.  I can see how to construct a recurrence relation, but I will have to solve a cubic equation to get the roots, is that correct?  And then I need 3 equations to find the constants, one is at n=0, one is with the limit you mentioned, but where do I get the 3rd one?

Comment: The equation has root $1$ guaranteed, so you are left with a quadratic equation one of which roots (which is greater than $1$ in absolute value) you can eliminate since $p(n)\in [0,1]$. So you have $2$ boundary conditions and $2$ variables.

Comment: @A.S. Excellent, thank you very much, I was able to solve it and find the same recurrence relation p_n=1-(\sqrt 2-1)^n as you did.  But what happens if there are more elements in the equation?  If you can jump to 10 different squares instead of 2 or 3, do you have to solve a 10th degree polynomial equation or is there a more general method?

Comment: I don't know a more general method - you'll need to solve 10th degree equation (and remember that your initial conditions are not just $p(0)=0$ but $p(\le 0)=0$). I don't know if the solution will be unique, but it seems plausible if you include non-decreasiness of $p(n)$ - though just the limit at $\infty$ could be enough. You need to investigate.

Comment: @A.S. Ok, thanks.  Although I don't understand what you mean by $p(\le 0)=$?  (If you put a negative value for n in the equation $p_n=1-(\sqrt 2-1)^n$ it will not work.)

Answer (score 0):

After one minute, The frog is two times as likely to be forward as backward. After two minutes the frog is either in the same place,forward, or two meters back. The chance of being forward is clearly $1-(1 /3)^2$ and thus $3^2-1 = 8$ times greater than the chance of being two steps behind 20 ($1/3)^2$. We can group the minutes into two-minute periods, so we can consider the frog to be moving forward or backward each period, where forward movement by 2 steps is $(3^2-1)$ times as likely as otherwise. Repeating the argument inductively, we eventually find that frog is (3^20-1) times more likely to reach 0 first 20 steps behind initial position , and thus the probability is $\frac{1}{3^{20}-1}$ the frog will be eaten by the cat **first**.

Comment: This is faulty reasoning leading to an answer that doesn't satisfy necessary recursion.

Comment: The probabillity you get is (very close to) the same as the probabillity that the frog steps back $20$ times in a row. This is not the only way to get eaten.

Comment: That is the reason, why I had included a word called "first".  You are right there are many more ways to get eaten by a combiination of forward and backward movement.